# Running OpenModelica GUI from Docker causes "Could not connect to any X display" error

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine, openmodelica

On [Modelica Language Discord](https://discordapp.com/invite/bp2yeYU), [someone posted](https://discordapp.com/channels/384316553497280512/384323177557262339/699899232236208168) the commands to get the OpenModelica GUI (OMEdit) running on Linux:

```
xhost +"local:docker@"
docker run -ti --rm --privileged --net=host -e "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix openmodelica/openmodelica:v1.14.1-gui OMEdit
```

and [someone else posted](https://discordapp.com/channels/384316553497280512/384323177557262339/699908250690256957) the below command for macOS:

```
docker run -ti --rm --privileged --net=host -e DISPLAY=docker.for.mac.localhost:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix openmodelica/openmodelica:v1.14.1-gui OMEdit
```

I have installed Docker using HomeBrew following the instructions [here](https://medium.com/@yutafujii_59175/a-complete-one-by-one-guide-to-install-docker-on-your-mac-os-using-homebrew-e818eb4cfc3)

```
docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
```

but when trying the command above I get the error message:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display docker.for.mac.localhost:0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Things I have tried to solve the problem:

- from [here](https://discordapp.com/channels/384316553497280512/384323177557262339/699899848207499265) installed dbus `brew install dbus`
- from [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/start-a-gui-application-as-root-in-a-ubuntu-container/17069) ran `xhost +local:docker` returning

> non-network local connections being added to access control list

- from [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-gui-apps-in-containiers-in-osx-docker-for-mac/17797) and [here](https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/155#issuecomment-228984599) changed `DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY` leading to slightly different error

> qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display unix/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.lO0ZFXT603/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

- from [here](https://github.com/xorilog/docker-telegram/blob/master/README.md), I tried

```
IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')
docker run .... -e DISPLAY=$(xhost + $(hostname) > /dev/null; echo $IP):0 ...
```

leading to

> qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 10.0.0.9:0

- from [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-run-ROS-robotic-operating-system-inside-a-Docker-and-have-X11-outputs-from-GUI-tools/answer/Taiping-Zeng?ch=2&srid=iETG), I tried the `open -a XQuartz`, ... `xhost + $ip`, and `DISPLAY=$ip:0`

I would appreciate if you could help me know

- How can I resolve the above issues and get the GUI running
- breakdown down the above commands for me. some of them are explained [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-gui-apps-in-containiers-in-osx-docker-for-mac/17797), but not the rest.

**P.S.** I don't want to install Docker Desktop as discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/g1oafc/how_to_install_docker_on_macos_using_homebrew/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

Answer (score 4):

OK, I think I was able to solve the problem. I assume `XQuartz` and `socat` are installed

```
brew cask install xquartz
brew install socat
```

then from [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8710#issuecomment-71113263), run

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
```

in one terminal. Open a new terminal and run

```
docker-machine env default
eval $(docker-machine env default)
IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')
xhost + $IP
docker run -ti --rm --privileged --net=host -e DISPLAY=$IP:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix openmodelica/openmodelica:v1.14.1-gui OMEdit
```

But still, I would appreciate it if someone could explain what these commands do and if there is a more clean and canonical way to do it.

**P.S.** Please consider that the `docker-machine` is deprecated software as of now. Please use it at your own risk. You need to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294241/4999991) to get it up and running.

Comment: What is `docker-machine` command here in the last part? I don't have such command but docker is installed on my host machine

Comment: @sgtpepper you may install it with `brew install docker-machine`

Comment: If you get "Docker machine "default" does not exist" Foad recommended trying this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294241/539490

Comment: @AJP Just added a **P.S.**