# docker-machine unable to create a machine on macOS, VBoxManage returning E_ACCESSDENIED error

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I have `docker`, `docker-machine`, and `virtualbox` installed using HomeBrew:

```
Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396e18
docker-machine version 0.16.2, build bd45ab1
VBoxManage version 6.1.30r148432
```

when I try creating a new machine

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

I get the below errors:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying /Users/foobar/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/foobar/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Found a new host-only adapter: "vboxnet0"
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.99.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 failed:
VBoxManage: error: Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) - Access denied (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "EnableStaticIPConfig(Bstr(pszIp).raw(), Bstr(pszNetmask).raw())" at line 242 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

I have tried many things

- reinstalling all of my packages
- running the above command in `sudo`
- using the `kextload` as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743478/4999991) to "enable kernel extensions"
- checking if there are any orphaned machines from past as suggested [here](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/1706#issuecomment-368496312) with `docker-machine ls`

to no avail. Apparently the issue is caused by the IP restriction for Host-Only networks in the newer versions of VirtualBox. [Some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69745931/4999991) suggesting a manual edit of the VirtualBox's `networks.conf` file. But I can't find it on my machine, nor I know what I should change there!

**P.S.1.** Asked a follow-up question [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/rc1s58/how_to_solve_the_e_accessdenied_0x80070005_error/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: Not sure what's causing this problem exactly but try downgrading to **VirtualBox 6.1.26** that might solve your problem.

Comment: @AffésSalem rather not to that, unless a more canonical solution is found. I am thinking if/how I can edit the `networks.conf` file to extend the IP range, If just could find where it is located first!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Thanks to [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/rc1s58/comment/hnskfau/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on Reddit, I was able to figure the issue out:

1. find all the machines with `docker-machine ls`
2. remove the ones you don't need with `docker-machine rm -y <machineName>`
3. find all the "host-only ethernet adapters" with `VBoxManage list hostonlyifs`
4. Remove the orphaned ones with `VBoxManage hostonlyif remove <networkName>`
5. Create a `vbox` folder in the `etc` directory with `sudo mkdir`
6. Create a file `networks.conf` in the `vbox` folder, for example by `sudo touch`
7. place the below line there

```
* 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0
```

8. create a new machine with `docker-machine create -d virtualbox <machineName>`
9. Run the command `eval $(docker-machine env <machineName>)` to configure your shell

**P.S.1.** One major drawback of the above solution is that every time you start the docker machine with `docker-machine start <machineName>` It takes a lot of time on `Waiting for an IP...`

Comment: @fips your welcome. It took me 4-5 nights to figure this out. frustrating!

Comment: You don't need to delete the entire machine (thankfully!). Steps 3-7 followed by `docker-machine start` work for me.

Comment: @Stu in my case because I had a lot of trial and error, it was a mess. But if you only have one docker-machine and no orphaned "host-only ethernet adapters", it should be OK.

Comment: Docker-machine has been archived (basically deprecated). Docker no longer supports it and I wouldn't recommend using it for any new use cases. https://github.com/docker/machine

Comment: @BMitch you may see [this page](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2596#issuecomment-600145238) to know why I detest Docker Desktop.

Comment: Thank you, Foad and everyone am struggling with another issue here "unning pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory" any help is welcome,  I am on macOS (Monetary) Virtual box and Linux ubuntu-20