# How to configure docker-machine without errors: Error setting up host only network on machine start, MAC M1?

Tags: docker, macos, virtualbox

I am trying to install docker on Mac M1. I installed docker using the command: `brew install docker-machine docker`.

Then, I installed virtualbox  with this command: `brew install --cask virtualbox`.

Then, when I tried to Configure docker-machine:  `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`, I got this error:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
```

So, I used the command:   `docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check default` to avoid the above error. However, this time I struggled with this error:

```
(default) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(default) 0%...NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(default) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(default) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(default) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(default) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 105 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(default) 
(default) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
```

I tried different solutions on the web, including:
restart my computer -> nothing changed.
trying to install VirtualBox version 5.0.12 -> unable to install it it always give me an error: `Warning: Cask 'virtualbox@5.0.12' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

What should I do to avoid this error and configure my docker-machine without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install VirtualBox 5.0.12 by downloading the DMG file [from the official source](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.12/) but considering you're on a M1, this version is probably not compatible with you macOS version. I'm on Monterey and version 5.0.12 is incompatible.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294241/5621295) on another post might be helpful to you.